# How to make a Stackoverflow-like Title bar (row) with UIKit

Tags: javascript, html, css, getuikit

I'm trying to make a similar title bar (or form row) like of StackOverflow with [UIKit](http://getuikit.com) with this code:

```
<div class="uk-form-row">
        <label class="uk-small-1-1 uk-large-1-10 uk-form-label">Text Title: </label>
        <input class="uk-small-1-1 uk-large-9-10 uk-float-right" type="text" value="" placeholder="Text title">
</div>
```

Here's a screenshot of what it looks like now:

[image]

Comment: Wait, what? [You mean this isn't an iOS question?](http://getuikit.com) ಠ_ಠ

Comment: Yes, uikit = http://getuikit.com (sorry I did not see the tag description right away, I am just adding the link ot UIKit)

Comment: Don't worry, it's not your fault. But whoever made this could have picked a name that wasn't already taken by a well-known technology for the past seven years...